# Javascript working on mac(chrome) but not in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

`document.getElementById('sVIN').value = "1FMDU34X6RUC10442"`

is running inside google chrome console on mac on this [webpage](http://owner.ford.com/servlet/ContentServer?pagename=Owner/Page/RecallsPage)
but not inside iPad UIWebView using:

```
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
```

There is no error log, I can run javascripts on other websites similarly, so there is no problem in code. ***What is the possible reason and workaround?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the case and it's true that code is not working.

But then I created an experiment - I delayed the evaluation.
Then the action worked.

What I've done as first was:

```
- (void) test {
    [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
}
```

then used:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(test) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
```

And it worked.
I suppose that your code is evaluating before the DOM is ready.

There are many ways to prevent such situation.

Let's say you don't have an access to the site, so all server-side javascripts (e.g. $(document).ready() {}) are no go.

From iOS you can implement completion callback for webView:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
}
```

Don't forget about delegating webview and adding protocol  to parent class:

```
webview.delegate = self;
```

I've checked and it worked.
In case it's not working for you - it's something wrong with site which makes the DOM not ready even if iOS webview thinks that it's finished.
If so, combine two resolutions I've described - so evaluate the JS with after delay in webViewDidFinishLoad callback:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [self performSelector:@selector(yourMethodWithJS) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}
```

I realize that the last advice it's not completely elegant approach but that't what you have to do if you're not in charge of fixing the site.

Comment: something wrong with website is that it loads multiple times, and webpage is not displayed on the first load but after all loads have finished(when the javascripts are called after the first load).
Thanks for research.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the code in simulator then go to Safari on your mac and activate Develop menu if you haven't already.

[image: check Develop menu at the bottom]

Then in Safari (on your mac) click Develop->Simulator and select the offending UIWebview. This will give you an inspector window to debug your UIWebview. You can debug your UIWebview like a regular website.

Hope this helps.